# How to use Javascript Registry with Bun?

Tags: npm, bun

I'm trying to install an NPM package via the new [JSR](https://jsr.io/) package registry with the following command:

`bunx jsr add -D @jsr/total-typescript__ts-reset`

The command did generate a bunfig.toml, but did not install my dependency nor update my package.json file [like it's supposed to](https://jsr.io/docs/using-packages).

Here is the bunfig.toml that it created:

```
[install.scopes]
"@jsr" = "https://npm.jsr.io"
```

And here is the error it throws:

```
Setting up bunfig.toml...ok
Installing @total-typescript/ts-reset...
$ bun add --dev @total-typescript/ts-reset@npm:@jsr/total-typescript__ts-reset
bun add v1.0.35 (940448d6)
   @jsr/total-typescript__ts-reset [1/1]
error: package "@jsr/total-typescript__ts-reset" not found npm.jsr.io/@jsr%2ftotal-typescript__ts-reset 404
error: @total-typescript/ts-reset@npm:@jsr/total-typescript__ts-reset failed to resolve
Child process exited with: 1
```

Isn't JSR supposed to [resolve to NPM](https://youtu.be/dHfZiqVWVhk?si=9psWSZmDObNooq7A&t=505) if it can't find the package in the registry? Am I just executing the command incorrectly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You mixed two possible syntaxes.

The command you want to run is:

`bunx jsr add -D @total-typescript/ts-reset`

---

The other alternative is to declare how to use the `jsr` registry. In that case you first have to create an `.npmrc` file, and add the following lines to it:

`@jsr:registry=https://npm.jsr.io`

Then, you can install with `bun add`:

`bun add -D @jsr/total-typescript__ts-reset`

(Notice how the package name is different.)